# PHP Need to remove a link from bottom of widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove a link from the bottom of a GPL WordPress plugin...I had installed the plugin but link still coming under it...

I had find the code in PHP file and here is the code...if i remove or edit any of the code widget will disappear..kindly advice to edit...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        jQuery(function() { jQuery("#calculator_widget").MortgageCalculator({ mode: "<?php echo ($instance['mode']) ? $instance['mode'] : 'widget';?>", animate: "<?php echo $instance['animate']?>", title: "<?php echo $instance['title']?>", footer: 'Powered by <?php echo get_option('loan_init')?>', intro: "<?php echo $instance['intro']?>", <?php echo get_option('calculator_code')?>});}); 

    </script>
```

and other piece in php file is this...i thinks these 2 codes are related...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="'.$x.'mlcalc.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function() { jQuery("#calculator_widget").MortgageCalculator({ mode: "normal", animate: "1", title: "'.$title.'", footer: \'Powered by '.$init.'\', intro: "'.$intro.'", '.$code.'});}); 

    </script>
```

In case any other file or complete code required please advice....see the link here at bottom of widget **powered by repaid.org**

[http://www.emortgagecalculator.org/](http://www.emortgagecalculator.org)

Comment: easiest way, just find where the link is generated, and add a class to the link. now in your site's css, just set that class to `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways.......

morgage calculator where it says footer, delete the content inbetween the two '' (id say it might require some value so you are passing in blank!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    jQuery(function() { jQuery("#calculator_widget").MortgageCalculator({ mode: "<?php echo ($instance['mode']) ? $instance['mode'] : 'widget';?>", animate: "<?php echo $instance['animate']?>", title: "<?php echo $instance['title']?>", footer: '', intro: "<?php echo $instance['intro']?>", <?php echo get_option('calculator_code')?>});}); 

</script>
```

or

```
.mc-footer{display:none;}
```

in your style.css.

Comment: Hello David thanks for the reply..I tried removing the function but nothing happens...this time widget will not disappear.. Advice me where to add the code in css some particular location

Comment: in your theme their is a file called style.css, just put it in there to test, if you're happy with it, create a child theme!

Comment: this script is called a function "function mcalc_init()" see the full function code here including function    http://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-to-remove-a-link-from-plugin-footer-1?replies=0

Comment: no....have a look in your wp-content/themes folder/ active theme...there is a file called style.css